# Class Inheritance: error saying that object has no attribute

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, attributes

Whenever I attempt to run the sleep method in the vampire(monster) class the following error occurs:
`AttributeError: 'vampire' object has no attribute 'hasCastle'`
The error is linked to line 8 of the code. 
I don't understand why this is happening as I am new to inheritance.

Code:

```py
class vampire(monster):
    def _init__(self, givenHasCastle, givenStrength, givenName):
        super().__init__(givenStrength, givenName)
        self.hasCastle = givenHasCastle

    def drinkBlood(self):
            print(self.name+" the vampire drinks the hero's blood.")

    def sleep(self):
        if self.hasCastle == True:
         print("The vampire sleeps silently in their castle.")
        else:
            print("The vampire sleeps silently in the wilderness.")
```

Comment: Typo: Missing underscore for `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

hasCastle will act as local variable, declare it as class variable won't show you that error.

Comment: There is no `hasCastle` local variable anywhere, the code only refers to the `self.hasCastle` attribute of self, which doesn't exist (cf the error message) because of the typo on the name of `__init__`, as explained in the comment. Note that such typo questions should not be answered, as their destiny is to get closed and deleted. A comment to help the OP notice it is enough before that.